# No default constructor exists for child - c++

Tags: c++

When I include child.h and make a variable of child it say no default constructor exists for child? Btw am is this:

```
Child::Child(const Child& otherChild) {
    this->name = otherChild.GetName();
}
```

the right way to make a copy constructor. And can I pass in a pointer into this copy constructor? Or should it be like this if I want to pass in a pointer:

```
Child::Child(const Child *otherChild) {
    this->name = otherChild->GetName();
}
```

parent:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include "Child.h"

using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    Parent(string name);
    Parent(const Parent& otherParent);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const Parent& parent);
    Parent operator=(const Parent& otherParent) const;
    string GetParentName() const;
    Child GetChild() const;

private:
    string name;
    Child myChild;

};
```

cpp:

```
#include "Child.h"

Child::Child(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

Child::Child(const Child& otherChild) {
    this->name = otherChild.GetName();
}

string Child::GetName() const
{
    return name;
}
```

header:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class Child {
public:
    Child(string name);
    Child(const Child& otherChild);
    string GetName() const;

private:
    string name;
};
```

Comment: So ... what exactly is your question?

Comment: 1.Why am i getting the no default constuctor error 2. Is my copy constructor correct so it can recieve a pointer.

Comment: Don't pass a pointer. Pointers are unnecessary and introduce the possibility for dangerous errors

Comment: 1. Because you have no default constructor (and you're trying to construct an object without arguments). 2. If it's a copy constructor, it can't receive a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Child` class can only be constructed by supplying arguments to a constructor; you have not provided a "default constructor" with no arguments.  Therefore, every constructor of your Parent class needs to provide arguments to initialize its `Child` member.  You need to do it before the body of the constructor actually starts running, so C++ has a special syntax for that.  It would look something like this:

```
Parent::Parent(std::string name)
  : myChild("childname")
{
}
```

You might want to reconsider your class structure, since the way it is right now, every `Parent` object must have a `Child`; you don't really have a way to express childless parents.

Comment: Aaah I understand!

Comment: What if myChild is a pointer? Then it says const char cannot be used to initialize child.

Comment: If your child is a pointer you would have to do something like `myChild = new Child("foo");` (and don't forget to `delete` it later).

Answer (score 1):

The class Parent has data member of the type Child

```
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(string name);
    Parent(const Parent& otherParent);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const Parent& parent);
    Parent operator=(const Parent& otherParent) const;
    string GetParentName() const;
    Child GetChild() const;

private:
    string name;
    Child myChild;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

And for this data member there is called the default constructor because it seems you do not initialize the data member in the mem-initializer-list of the Parent constructor.

You need to initialize it something lie

```
Parent::Parent(string name) : myChild( SomeValue )
{
    //...
}
```